# Run web tests in parallel on mobile and desktop with unique driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, remotewebdriver

We have web application which supports desktop and mobile chrome browsers .
we are planning to create common driver for all platforms, like below

```
RemoteWebdriver driver=initializeMobileWebdriver() and
RemoteWebdrver driver=initializeDesktopWebdriver()
```

in test class , if I use if else then I can able to run tests in parallel on Bothe the devices but if I dont use then we can not run tests in parallel

what I want, I have to run same or different test on both mobile and desktop and then share the feedback.
can someone help to run tests in local and hybrid